# CheckOnClick doesn't work when drag-and-drop is implemented

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, click, checkedlistbox

I got the problem that I need a CheckedListBox where I can check the box by clicking at an item and also be able to reorder the Items by drag&drop.

I implemented this with the following code:

```
private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem == null)
        return;
    indexBefore = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedIndex;
    this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.DoDragDrop(this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = chLB_BenötigteProzesse.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    int index = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.IndexFromPoint(point);
    if (index < 0) index = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Count - 1;
    if (index == indexBefore)
    {
        this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SetItemChecked(index, !this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.GetItemChecked(index));
        return;
    }
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
    this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Remove(data);
    this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Insert(index, data);
}
```

The problem is, with the _MouseDown event the CheckOnClick is not working anymore. 
So I tried to fix this with the indexBefore = ... in _MouseDown and if (index == indexBefore)... in DragDrop. 
This is only working if I click at an Item and move it a little bit that it is being dragged at the same place as it was before. 
A simple click is also not working.

Next try was to use this mechanism at the _MouseUp event:

```
    private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = chLB_BenötigteProzesse.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index == indexBefore)
            this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SetItemChecked(index, !this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.GetItemChecked(index));
    }
```

But _MouseUp is never fired.

Can you tell me how to get this working as it should (simply click on an Item should check/uncheck it and drag&drop should be used to change the order)?
Does anyone know why the _MouseUp event isn't fired?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

With this Code it is working (couldn't use the e.LeftButton because it's winforms not wpf):

```
    private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = chLB_BenötigteProzesse.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index < 0) index = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Count - 1;
        if (index == indexBefore)
        {
            this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SetItemChecked(index, !this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.GetItemChecked(index));
            return;
        }

        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
        bool checkState = chLB_BenötigteProzesse.GetItemChecked(indexBefore);
        this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Remove(data);
        this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.Items.Insert(index, data);
        this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SetItemChecked(index, checkState);
    }

    private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dragDropEnabled || this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem == null || e.Location == mouseLocation)
            return;

        indexBefore = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedIndex;
        dragDropEnabled = false;
        this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.DoDragDrop(this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            dragDropEnabled = true;
            mouseLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: You should use english names for your methods and variables. At least here at StackOverflow.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The code is written in very bad denglish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use OnMouseMove instead of OnMouseDown and then check if the left mouse button is pressed to start your darag and drop operation as it is described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).

So the solution to your problem should be to replace chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseDown with:

```
private void chLB_BenötigteProzesse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed || this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem == null)
        return;
    indexBefore = this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedIndex;
    this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.DoDragDrop(this.chLB_BenötigteProzesse.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);    
}
```

Don't forget to detach your mouseDown handler and attach the new mouseMove handler!

Comment: Great, that's working. So for me to understand why `_MouseUp` isn't fired: Could it be that the `DoDragDrop()` blocks the events?